# Apache doesn't get connected in MAMP

Tags: macos, apache, web, mamp

You know why Apache Server doesn't get connected in MAMP? I have tried both ports 80 and 8888 none of which worked. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

I went to sharing in system preferences and this is what it was like. Please let me know if it should be different:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the apache process is still running in background.
Try to kill the **httpd** process and restart MAMP.

edit:
To do this:

1. Quit MAMP
2. Go to Utilities and open activity monitor
3. Look for httpd processes
4. Click **Quit process** and then **Force Quit**
5. Start MAMP

edit2: If you use MAMP make sure you **turn off** the **Personal Web Sharing**.
System Preferences. Click the Sharing tab, and then turn off the Personal Web
Sharing checkbox.

Comment: I tried this but still doesn't work: `sudo killall httpd
Password:
No matching processes were found`

Comment: I read somewhere that I should use this `sudo apachectl stop
launchctl: Error unloading: org.apache.httpd` but as you see it's not working

Comment: Well I first started and then stopped it but it's not helping me `monas-mbp:Downloads mona$ sudo apachectl start
monas-mbp:Downloads mona$ sudo apachectl stop`

Comment: try with mac **activity monitor** (Utilities)

Comment: there's no httpd in activity monitor!

Comment: Can you see the updated post? I have posted a picture of the sharing folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your MAMP folder in Applications. Go to bin -> apache2 -> bin:

Then rename the file from "envvars" to "_envvars".

ref: [Apache not starting on MAMP Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201280/apache-not-starting-on-mamp-pro)