# Apache not starting on MAMP Pro

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp, diagnostics, mamp-pro

Apache wont start and it throws an error:

[image: Starting Apache failed screenshot]

OR
Apache couldn't be started. Please check the log file for more information.

> dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv
>     Referenced from: /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
>     Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
>    in /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
>   /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl: line 80:  2799 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $HTTPD "$

This is the same for multiple ports. The reccomended MAMP ports AND the regular apache ports.

MySQL starts perfectly fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running Mavericks? I just got the same error and I just upgraded Java and Mavericks... I'll let you know if I come up with a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MAMP Pro 3.05 on Mavericks updated to Yosemite - Apache does not start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139599/mamp-pro-3-05-on-mavericks-updated-to-yosemite-apache-does-not-start)

Answer (score 395, accepted):

I updated to the latest version of yosemite last night.

You apparently have to go to your MAMP folder in Applications. Go to `bin` -> `apache2` -> `bin`.

Then rename the file from `envvars` to `_envvars`.

I also came across another problem of it not working correctly. Make sure the ports are Apache defaults, NOT MAMP defaults (port 80 etc). If it works straight away, this should not apply to you.

Comment: Thank you! Worked! 

For others, clear solution: 
cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin && 
sudo mv envvars _envvars

Comment: Just updated to mavericks too and had the same problem. You sir, is awesome.

Comment: If you're running Yosemite and this answer doesn't work for you, do this first : backup your MAMP directory, remove MAMP and MAMP Pro, reinstall 3.0.5, perform the trick in the answer, then restore your htdocs, confs and db directories from your backup. Apache will then start.

Comment: Just wondering what the reason is for this change to envvars? It has to do with Yosemite environment declarations?

Comment: Just a note apache port works with me on **port 80**. The default MAMP seems to be 8888 which doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @Toby After applying your fix mySQL is getting a socket error and can't find mysql **#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket** ? Any ideas?

Comment: I was using Mamp 2 and could not get Apache to start, then updated to Mamp 3 and everything worked fine.

Comment: @Dano check the filename spelling, there are typos in the command. Should be __cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin && sudo mv envvars _envvars__.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the latest release of MAMP 3 Version 3.0.7.3 in my case seems to solve this issue.

Comment: Im facing the same issue now in OS X El Captain , i have upgraded to  3.0.7.3 but still cant run apache. Can anyone hel me . thanks

Comment: @Delavega, if you still have this problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34425292/2913356