# Apache Not Starting But MySQL Does

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

I am attempting to start my MAMP servers however it is erroring and saying to check the error log to fix the issue but there is so much that is in there I'm not sure what to look for because the Apache is not starting but MySQL is.

Can someone clue me into how to find this out.

[image]

Comment: you should refer to the documentation to see where logs are placed and at least post them here, it really difficult to answer such question, and maybe serverfault.com should be a better place to ask.

Comment: Is there a tool that will go in and fix what is wrong with Yosemite and MAMP Pro?

Comment: It works one computer but not another.

Comment: that would probably be a magic wand!

Comment: Is there a file I could copy over from one computer to another that would fix the issue.

Comment: Without knowing what the issue is, you understand that this is really difficult.

Comment: I'll post a picture and see if that is of any help.

Comment: this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201280/apache-not-starting-on-mamp-pro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65726/discussion-between-drc-and-user3732216).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this. My usual voodoo to fix it is:

- re-assign all error log files (no matter if you think they are already right)
- restart the Mac
- stop the OS X Apache from running (menu Tools -> stop system Apache)

Greetings,
Peter