# MAMP Latest 3.0 Apache won't start on Yosemite Version 10.10.3

Tags: apache, mamp, osx-yosemite

I updated my MAMP to the latest version 3.0 today, due to the fact of the Apache issue on the old version.

Still the Apache issue persist. This time the `envvars` in the latest MAMP is named `envvars_`

I tried to renamed it to `_envvars` or *`_envvars_`* but the apache still doesn't run.

I also tried different ports.

***I decided to update my MAMP, because when I tried _envvars on the old version of MAMP and my Apache start running but mySQL didn't and I read that with the new version of MAMP this issue will be resolved.

Anybody experienced the same issue? Any solution or work around with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue here. [These](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139599/mamp-pro-3-05-on-mavericks-updated-to-yosemite-apache-does-not-start) [solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201280/apache-not-starting-on-mamp-pro) do not work.

Comment: *Update*: I have opened a support ticket to MAMP in regards to this issue.

Comment: *Update*: MAMP have responded to say that they will remove the offending line `LoadModule example_module modules/mod_example.so` in `httpd.conf` in the next release. In the meantime, see T.T's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Did you retain your original httpd.conf from before the upgrade? You may have to edit the modules in your httpd.conf.

I had to run `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl configtest`  to display which modules to remove.

I commented out a `example_module`.

```
#LoadModule example_module modules/mod_example.so
```

Comment: This is the solution for me. Well found. This line was uncommented on the latest binary release I downloaded. I'd love to know why they did this.

Comment: Hi T.T., how will I be able to comment out the LoadModule in the httpd.conf file, what editor can I use to comment it out since no apps in my mac can open it  e.g. like sublime text. Thanks.

Comment: @nycdanie Sublime Text is perfect for this, but any other text editor will do. Just right click (ctrl + click) on the file, and choose 'Open With...'

Comment: @nycdanie No problem. As T.T's answer has essentially pointed out the bug, you should 'accept' it so that he/she receives the SO points they deserve.

Comment: This saved my life. Thanks a million